# not able to make TextView as focusable

Tags: android

hi im using 3 text views ..i have made them as clickable and i have written action part for those ..but theyr not focussing ...even i have set android:focusable to true  ..please help

Comment: do you want the text view to get focus when it gets click or always?

Comment: hi shaireen when i move through the joystick of mobile it should get focus..that means with some other color..is there any code for that..thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an image as the background of the button. if so the focus will not appear on button.

Comment: no dude im not using image as the background it is just plain textview now im able to make focus on it ..but i dont knoe how to change the color of it when it gets focus..

Comment: You can use the following link for color change

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Comment: you can use it like this:res/button_dark_text.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>

Comment: then make
res/layout/view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
    <Button
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="EXIT"
              android:textColor="@drawable/button_dark_text" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: let me know you get it implemented or not.

Comment: create the button_dark_text.xml like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EXIT" android:textColor="@drawable/button_dark_text" /> </LinearLayout>file in your drawable folder

Comment: then add this xml file in your main.xml layout like this:                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ADD NEW NOTES" android:textColor="@drawable/button_dark_text" /> </LinearLayout>

Comment: still the same i will givw u the code.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#f1f1f1"/>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#F2F2F2" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#F3F3F3" />
   <item android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
 </selector>  this is in colorstatelist.xml

Comment: <TextView android:text="ADD NEW NOTES" 
    android:id="@+id/newtask1" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/colorstatelist"
    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="@string/onaddclick" android:clickable="true" android:linksClickable="true" android:focusable="true" >
    
    </TextView>  this is my textview..chk it out..